# Getting MissingDLL error in Mono

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, mono, centos

So I'm trying to run a small Console app via mono on CentOS, but I need to use 3 Visual-C++ Libraries as part of the requirements.

Whenever I try and run the .net app on CentOS I get an exception citing that vsruntime140d.dll is missing (which I've learned is the .net assembly for c/c++ in vs2015)

I've configured my C++ apps to be /clr:safe, set their Windows SDK version to Win10 and Set their Platform Toolset to VS 2017 (which I've ran, but I've tried 2015 as well). In the linker I've set it to Ignore Default Libraries /NODEFAULTLIB

I've tried building these apps in windows then copying the binary and assemblies over to centos, then running mono Application.exe but it returns

`Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception. ---> <CrtImplementationDetails>.ModuleLoadException: The C++ module failed to load during appdomain initialization.
 ---> System.DllNotFoundException: VCRUNTIME140D.dll
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal:Prelink (System.Reflection.MethodInfo)
  at <Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.ForceLoadRuntimeApis (<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport* ) [0x00093] in <10c169d804e4480ab7903a570bc3de2b>:0 
  at <Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.InitializePerAppDomain (<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport* ) [0x00012] in <10c169d804e4480ab7903a570bc3de2b>:0 
  at <Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport._Initialize (<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport* ) [0x00015] in <10c169d804e4480ab7903a570bc3de2b>:0 
  at <Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize (<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport* ) [0x00010] in <10c169d804e4480ab7903a570bc3de2b>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at <Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.ThrowModuleLoadException (System.String errorMessage, System.Exception innerException) [0x00007] in <10c169d804e4480ab7903a570bc3de2b>:0 
  at <Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize (<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport* ) [0x00026] in <10c169d804e4480ab7903a570bc3de2b>:0 
  at <Module>..cctor () [0x00008] in <10c169d804e4480ab7903a570bc3de2b>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Application.Program.Main () [0x00029] in <2ff592459ad74d828ffa904fe73703f3>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception. ---> <CrtImplementationDetails>.ModuleLoadException: The C++ module failed to load during appdomain initialization.
 ---> System.DllNotFoundException: VCRUNTIME140D.dll
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal:Prelink (System.Reflection.MethodInfo)
  at <Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.ForceLoadRuntimeApis (<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport* ) [0x00093] in <10c169d804e4480ab7903a570bc3de2b>:0 
  at <Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.InitializePerAppDomain (<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport* ) [0x00012] in <10c169d804e4480ab7903a570bc3de2b>:0 
  at <Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport._Initialize (<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport* ) [0x00015] in <10c169d804e4480ab7903a570bc3de2b>:0 
  at <Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize (<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport* ) [0x00010] in <10c169d804e4480ab7903a570bc3de2b>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at <Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.ThrowModuleLoadException (System.String errorMessage, System.Exception innerException) [0x00007] in <10c169d804e4480ab7903a570bc3de2b>:0 
  at <Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize (<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport* ) [0x00026] in <10c169d804e4480ab7903a570bc3de2b>:0 
  at <Module>..cctor () [0x00008] in <10c169d804e4480ab7903a570bc3de2b>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Application.Program.Main () [0x00029] in <2ff592459ad74d828ffa904fe73703f3>:0`

Would anyone have any ideas on how to get this app to run on CentOS?

Comment: You can't use a VisualC++ dll on Linux, it's not portable. If you need to use native C functions then you should write it in plain C or C++ and compile it on each platform you plan to use it.

Comment: You would need to (cross-)compile those C++ libraries for CentOS

Comment: Is this an application you've written yourself? Or do you have some other reason to believe it should run on Mono?  Personally I'd be rather surprised there was a version of VCRUNTIME140D compiled for a non-Windows platform - it's distributed as a native library normally.

Comment: The Libraries are already written in Visual-C++, but I do have access to the source code.

Comment: The Application itself is written in c#

Answer (score 0):

see this:  [Unable to use C++/CLI assembly in .NET](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/96177/unable-to-use-ccli-assembly-in-net-with-multiple-a.html)

looks like a compiler regression.
the suggestion in that thread is to update to VS2017 15.5 preview 2 and see if its gone.